# Comparing variables in a list

Tags: python, compare

I have a list of numbers:

```
x = [601.4, 603.6, 600.5, 605.7]
```

and when a value in the list is within +1 of another one, I want to set a boolean variable to true.

So this:

```
i = 0
while i < 4:
   if x[i] smart function here
      y = True
   else:
      y = False
   print (y)
   i = i + 1
```

would give out:

```
True
False
False
False
```

Comment: Why isn't the third result true? `600.5` is within 1 of another value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `map` the checking function `f = lambda v: -1.0 <= v - x[i] <= 0.0` on the list `x[0:i] + x[i+1:]` that excludes the current index. Finally, check the created iterable of the map result with `any`.

```
x = [601.4, 603.6, 600.5, 605.7]

i = 0
while i < 4:
    f = lambda v: -1.0 <= v - x[i] <= 0.0
    if any(map(f, x[0:i] + x[i+1:])):
        y = True
    else:
        y = False
    print (y)
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: `True if condition else False` can be expressed as `condition`.

Answer (score 0):

```html
x = [601.4, 603.6, 600.5, 605.7]

for value in x:
    y = False
    for val in x:
        if val != value:
            if val < value < val + 1:
                y = True
                break
    print(y)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).